# Retrieving entire lines of text where unique keywords appear from a PDF using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe, acrobat

From Excel, I need to open an existing pdf file, search for a unique text string, and copy the entire line where the string is found into the Excel sheet.

I do not have access to the Pro version of Acrobat so I have utilized VBA to open the PDF file via the FollowHyperlink method, and locate the unique text string successfully via the use of Sendkeys to talk to the PDF Find box (yeah, I know it is somewhat flaky but this is a low volume activity), but I have not been able to figure out how to retrieve the entire line of text where the unique text was found so that I can add it to an Excel sheet. My code so far is:

```
         PDF_path = TempFolder & SA_File_Name ' complete path to rpt
    
        'Open the pdf file
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDF_path
    
        'Wait time for a couple of seconds for the PDF file to fully load
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
        'Send "CTRL + F" keys to the opened PDF to invoke find within that file
        'The second argument "true" implies that Excel will wait for the keys to be processed
        'before returning control to the macro.
    
        SendKeys "^f", True
    
        'Your search string - case-insensitive, as in actual PDF search
        PDFSearchString = "Security Audits"
        'Type the search string in the find box that opens
        SendKeys PDFSearchString, True
        'Hit enter to perform the search
        SendKeys "{Enter}", True
```

Here is where I want to get the entire line and copy it to a sheet.

Comment: If you open your PDF file in Notepad, can you CTRL-F to find your search word? Sometimes you can extract text by reading the binary of the file into a string..

Comment: I tried the suggestion regarding the Home and End keys which work very well as long as I am manually in the PDF, but I am unable to get the following code the pick up the entire line (it just picks up the first keyword of the find argument):

Comment: Code:  'Your search string - case-insensitive, as in actual PDF search
            PDFSearchString = "Security Audits"
            'Type the search string in the find box that opens
            SendKeys PDFSearchString, True
            'Hit enter to perform the search
            SendKeys "{Enter}", False
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            
            SendKeys "+{Home}"
            SendKeys "+{End}"
            SendKeys "^c"

Comment: I solved this issue by using VBA to open Acrobat Reader and convert the content to text, save this text in an empty sheet in the workbook, and then search the text to find the keywords:

Comment: 'code': SearchArg = "Database Name:"
            Set Found = wsWork.Cells.Find(What:=SearchArg, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate